# Yii: Can not list data in Grid View

Tags: php, yii

I cant list data in grid using yii framework.My controller is Sitecontroller.php,My view is list_jobseeker.php .I got the error "Fatal error: Call to a member function getData() on a non-object ".Anybody help me?

My controller code

```
  public function actionlist_jobseeker()
  {
  $session_id=Yii::app()->session['user_id']; 
  if ($session_id == "")
    {
        $this->redirect( array('/employee/site/login'));
    }
  $user_id  =$session_id;
  $models = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
     ->select('*')
     ->from('job_seeker_profile s')
     ->join('job_profile j','s.user_id = j.user_id')
     ->order('s.id')
     ->queryAll();
     $this->render('list_jobseeker',array('models' =>$models));
```

}

View-  list_jobseeker.php

```
<h1>View Jobseeker</h1>

<div class="flash-success">

</div>

 <div class="form">
 <?php
  $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'rates-phase-grid',
   'htmlOptions' => array('class' => 'table table-striped table-bordered table-hover'),
    'dataProvider'=>new CArrayDataProvider($models),
    'columns' => array(
        array(
            'name' => 'Name',
            'type' => 'raw',
            'value' => 'CHtml::encode($data[*]->name)',
            'htmlOptions' => array('style'=>'width:90px;','class'=>'zzz'),

     ),
        array(
            'name' => 'Email',
            'type' => 'raw',
            'value' => 'CHtml::encode($data[*]->email)',
            'htmlOptions' => array('style'=>'width:250px;','class'=>'zzz')

        ),
        array(
            'name' => 'Password',
            'type' => 'raw',
            'value' => 'CHtml::encode($data[*]->password)',
            'htmlOptions' => array('style'=>'width:90px;','class'=>'zzz')
        ),
        array(
            'name' => 'Contact No',
            'type' => 'raw',
            'value' => 'CHtml::encode($data[*]->contact_no)',
            'htmlOptions' => array('style'=>'width:40px;','class'=>'zzz')

        ),
         array(
            'name' => 'Gender',
            'type' => 'raw',
            'value' => 'CHtml::encode($data[*]->gender)',
            'htmlOptions' => array('style'=>'width:40px;','class'=>'zzz')

        ),


        array(
            'class' =>'CButtonColumn',
            'deleteConfirmation'=>'Are you sure you want to delte this item?',
            'template'=>'{update}{delete}',

            'buttons' =>array('update'=>array(

             'label'=>'edit',
      'url'=>'Yii::app()->controller->createUrl("UpdateJob",array("id"=>$data["id"]))',

                ),
             'delete'=>array('label'=>'delete',
     'url'=>'Yii::app()->controller->createUrl("DeleteJob",array("id"=>$data["id"]))'),


                )
            )
          ),
   ));
  ?>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Yii: Can not Display Data in Grid View](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23241291/yii-can-not-display-data-in-grid-view)

Answer (score 0):

`dataProvider` should be a [`CDataProvider`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDataProvider) instance. You are passing in an array: `$model`. You could wrap this in a [`CArrayDataProvider`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CArrayDataProvider):

```
'dataProvider' => new CArrayDataProvider($model),
```

A couple of other issues:

a) Your gridview expects `$data` to be an object and not an array. Either alter all `$data->*` instances to `$data[*]` or use `CActiveDataProvider` and the `CActiveRecord` instance for the `job_seeker_profile` table

b) By convention `$model` usually refers to a single `CModel` instance. Your array should therefore be named something else in plural e.g `$items`

Comment: hi, Now i got the error "Trying to get property of non-object

C:\wamp\www\yii_new\framework\base\CComponent.php(612) : eval()'d code(1)"

Comment: You are using the grid wrong. I have added a few issues with it. [But you need to read the manual](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CGridView)

Comment: Got the error "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '*', expecting ']' in C:\wamp\www\yii_new\framework\base\CComponent.php(612) : eval()'d code on line 1"

Comment: Topher,I had edited the view and controller page please look it.

Comment: You haven't read the manual. The answer is in the comments: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CGridView#c3 and http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CGridView#c2288

Comment: You have several issues in question, but before resolving one, you posted it again... And this could be resoved by reading manual. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23241291/yii-can-not-display-data-in-grid-view

Answer (score 0):

I use this:

```
    $data = ...::model()->findAll();
    $dataProvider=new CArrayDataProvider('Class of your object');
    $dataProvider->setData($data);
    $dataProvider->keyField = "primary key of your model";


    $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
...
array( 'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
                    'template' => '{ver}',
                    'buttons' => array(
                        'ver' => array(
                            'url'=>'"?id=".$data["..."]',
                        'imageUrl'=> Yii::app()->baseUrl.'/images/view.png',  //Image URL of the button.
                    ),
                )
            ),
```